# Sending variable with watchConnectivity but can't get the picker in the watch app to update

Tags: iphone, swift, apple-watch, watchconnectivity

I've been trying to send a variable to the watch from the iPhone. I've managed to send it with watchConnectivity but I can't get the picker in the watch app to update with the new variable I sent through.

Here's the code for the watch app:

```
import WatchKit
import Foundation
import WatchConnectivity

var bigDict = ["":""]

class InterfaceController: WKInterfaceController, WCSessionDelegate {

    lazy var keys = Array(bigDict.keys)
    lazy var values = Array(bigDict.values)
    var pickerItems: [WKPickerItem] = []

    @IBOutlet var pickerW: WKInterfacePicker!

    @IBAction func pickerDidChange(_ value: Int) {

    }

    @IBAction func updateButton() {
        for item in keys{
            let pickerItem = WKPickerItem()
            pickerItem.title = item
            pickerItem.caption = bigDict[item]
            pickerItems += [pickerItem]
        }
        pickerW.setItems(pickerItems)
    }

    //func refreshPickerItems() {
        //for item in keys{
            //let pickerItem = WKPickerItem()
            //pickerItem.title = item
            //pickerItem.caption = bigDict[item]
            //pickerItems += [pickerItem]
       // }

        //pickerW.setItems(pickerItems)

   // }


    override func awake(withContext context: Any?) {
        super.awake(withContext: context)
        // Configure interface objects here.
        //refreshPickerItems()
    }

    override func willActivate() {
        // This method is called when watch view controller is about to be visible to user
        super.willActivate()
        if WCSession.isSupported() {
            let session = WCSession.default
            session.delegate = self
            session.activate()
        }
    }

    func session(_ session: WCSession, activationDidCompleteWith activationState: WCSessionActivationState, error: Error?) {

    }

    func session(_ session: WCSession, didReceiveMessage message: [String : Any]) {

        print(message)
        bigDict = message as! [String : String]
            print(bigDict)
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please show us your current code.

Comment: added the watchKit code. thanks

Comment: WCSession callbacks occur on a background queue, while generally you'd want to make sure you update the UI elements on the main queue. Might be worth trying to dispatch to the main queue and see if that helps solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't you call "updateButton()" when you receive the data?

```
func session(_ session: WCSession, didReceiveMessage message: [String : Any]) {

    print(message)
    bigDict = message as! [String : String]
    updateButton()
    print(bigDict)


}
```